# Trying to remove this code without the need to put it in a seperate page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My index.html page has a fancy animation to begin with it is essentially this code below...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
       $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 11000);

 });
```

..... so once this code has run its 11 seconds it all gets unwrapped and thats great... Problem is I have an a tag to get back to the index page at any time and I don't want people to have to wait for the intro animation to run before getting to the homepage every time....

I will not accept any answer that says .."do the animation on a seperate page"  - the code has to be on the index page itself.

I was hoping there was some sort of jquery that will remove the code until the browser page has been refreshed, something like that.. Really appreciate any help here.

**EDIT** -- Getting some initial feedback that this is unclear ... in step for ...

1. User goes to index.html
2. the above code begins and lasts for 11 seconds.
3. then it gets unwrapped and disappears.
4. Seperatly while the user is enjoying the site they click on the "home" logo.
5. this takes people back to the index.html page
6. Unfortunately they have an 11 seconds wait every time and i want this to stop unless they refresh the browser or something.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying you want the animation to run on the index page, but you don't want it to run on the index page after the `a` has been clicked?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Do you want it to run on only the first time someone visits the index page, and not the second, third etc?

If so you'll have to use cookies or session info.

Comment: That's a little bit unclear what you're asking. Is the animation made with CSS? JS? Can't you just `$('everything').remove()` on click on the `a`?

Comment: almost, once the animation has finished is gets unwrapped , but if you click on the logo to go back to the index page that is there in the whole site it will naturally take you back through the animation first every time , ... i want to stop this from happening after the user has seem the animation once only , (unless they refresh their browser)

Comment: If you want the code to be on the page but not execute, then you need to define some *condition* by which to execute it.  What is that condition?  If it's "has the user already seen this animation" then how do you plan to track that piece of information?

Comment: david you are spot on ! basically I think that only if a browser refresh has occured then after the animation has run on the first time then dump it .... so basically only come back if browser is refreshed

Comment: is PHP and Javascript/jQuery acceptable?

Comment: i haven't used php in the site at all it is js and css but if you think it would help I am happy for that to happen , (you will have to explain about php though)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon  I think you are also onto something here... so a bit of jquery that says when the class assocaited with the A tag is clicked then remove the div/classes for animation , could you provide an example in this instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a cookie the 1st time that the users waits 11 secs

Can use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie or with native javascript code.

As well you can use a localstore var or url query

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     if ($.cookie("index_viewed") == 1) {
       return;
     } else {
       setTimeout(function() {
         $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
         $("#wrapper").unwrap();
         $.cookie("index_viewed", 1);
       }, 11000);
     }
 });
```

Comment: H iNada, Thanks for the reply... for some reason I couldn't get it to work , it just keeps running in a loop ? maybe running it locally is the problem hmmm

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like `localStorage` or cookies on your server side to manage this.

Here's the local storage example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if( !window.localStorage || !window.localStorage.getItem('hpAnim') ) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit, #logo, #wrapper").hide("slow"); 
      $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 11000);
    if( window.localStorage ) {
      window.localStorage.setItem('hpAnim', true)
    }
  }
} );
```

So now (in IE8+) the second and future pageloads will not run the animation.

On the other hand if you've got a single page JavaScript app and you want it to re-run only after page refresh (as per comments on question), then you can skip local storage and simply set a global variable on window:

```
window.hasSeenAnimation = true
```

And then check that condition before running the animation again. After a page refresh that variable will be gone.

Comment: Thats pretty damn cool and very much what I am thinking would work here... so only if they clear the cache they will be able to see the animation again ?

Comment: Right basically. I just updated to show how you'd do it so it resets on page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `$_GET` variable and then check for this. If it's there, it must be an internal link so don't load the animation:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/?noAnim">Home</a>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['noAnim']))
{
    ?>
    <script>
    // your animation script goes here....
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want that animation to run at "startup" (when directly pointed) you could check the tab history count:

```
history.length
```

This will return a value higher than 1 only if any navigation took place on the tab (going to index from any other page).
This is not a perfect solution though:

- Cross browser issues (some return 0, others 1)
- Every navigation on this tab will produce history, hence, if you navigate to your website after checking any other page, history will return a value higher than the initial. (you can also check the **document.referrer** to ease this issue)

If you can't afford to skip the animation on those conditions you must persist the fact that the animation had already ran, and you should aim for Local Storage, for example (as mentioned earlier) http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp